# Google My Business API - Use the UI to provide a pin drop

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business-api

I am trying to update a listing on Google My Business with a new description, in doing this you have to update the whole listing. When trying to update the address I get the response;

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
            "errorDetails": [
                {
                "code": 1100,
                "field": "address",
                "message": "The specified address cannot be located. Please use the UI to provide a pin drop."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The address is exactly the same as what has been retrieved from Google just 20 minutes earlier so there is no difference to what shows in Google. Is there any way to update this listing?

Google detail that you should use a UI to position the Map Pin to update the listing if this is done what is the new information provided back to Google?

Comment: I am also facing this issue now.  Ugh.  Did you have any luck figuring it out??  Ive tried a field mask for only the fields I wanna update.  That didnt work.  When I do a direct get request of the location, and send that exact object back as a patch request with no field mask, it also fails on the address.  On the exact same address google gives me in the GET request.  So wierd

Comment: Hello, any of you guys found the solution or not, I'm getting the same error when updating the location without the mask update option means full updates.